# How can I check that the NSString ends with the certain character(.jpg)?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I have a NSString object which is assigned this ("http://vspimages.vsp.virginia.gov/images/024937-02.jpg"). Can anybody tell me how to check whether the string ends with ".jpg"?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```
if ([[yourString pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"jpg"]){
   //.jpg
}
```

or

```
if ([yourString hasSuffix:@".jpg"]){
   //.jpg
}
```

Comment: i have already tried this [yourString hasSuffix:@".jpg"] this but its not working...

Comment: Have you tried to log your string to check if it has expected value? also I think, 1st approach is more appropriate in your case

Comment: You should really use a case insensitive compare

Answer (score 6):

appending to vladimir's answer, you may wish to make a case insensitive comparison. Here's how I did it:

```
if( [[yourString pathExtension] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"jpg"] == NSOrderedSame ) {
  // strings are equal but may not be same case
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.png' AND self BEGINSWITH[c] %@",@"img_"];
if([fltr evaluateWithObject:strPath])
{
    // string matched....
}
```